# Rails - Feedjira No valid parser for XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedjira

I used Feedjira gem in rails. I want to get some data from `URL` but I got an error like this:

> Feedjira::NoParserAvailable No valid parser for XML.

**My code:**

```
url = "https://tickets.companyname.com/activity.atom?key=#{api_key}&user_id=#{user_id}"
feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse url // this line i'm getting the error
```

Comment: Most time this message tells you, that it's either no valid Feed format or the format of the feed isn't known by feedjira. For a better help you will have to post the RAW feed (cleared from private data).

Comment: Are you getting a 200 response? Can you post the response data, meaning maybe use an HTTP client to get the response before parsing with Feedjira.